# Android. GcmNetworkManager on Firebase SDK?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, gcm-network-manager

After Firebase was announced at Google I/O 2016 I've read about migration of some changes that will affect my code, GCM to FCM, Analytics related changes etc...
but I didn't found any information about GcmNetworkManager , what happens with it ?

We have a new Task Scheduler ?

Remains the old one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

I'll offer the little that I know and hopefully a Firebase engineer with provide a more authoritative answer.

There seems to be work underway for a Firebase replacement to [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager).  It's [Firebase Android JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android):

> The Firebase Android JobDispatcher is a library that provides a
>   high-level wrapper around job scheduling engines on Android, starting
>   with the GCM Network Manager.
>
> This replaces the old GCM Network Manager library.

A note in the description states: *This library is actively supported by Google engineers*.

I haven't used it yet.  I'm still using `GcmNetworkManager`.  My app includes the `play-services-gcm` library along with most of the Firebase libraries. That doesn't appear to cause any conflicts.  My GCM tasks work as they did before I added Firebase.

Comment: Btw this is important information about new library
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/24

Comment: seems its premature to use it instead, doesn't seem to have any real extended functionality and just is a wrapper over GcmNetwork services a year later though they seem to WANT to make it independent